# every image on separate blank pages without page number

Tags: graphics, lyx, lyx-layouts, afterpage, everypage

I have my final year report.
I want to put **every images on separate blank pages (no text, only image) without page numbers**, keeping the rest of the text flow unaltered.

Is there some way of doing it as part of the latex processing?

Please help, i am trying to do this for last 4 days, still can't get solution.

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty} \begin{figure}...\end{figure}\clearpage \begin{figure}...\end{figure}\clearpage \begin{figure}...\end{figure}\clearpage \begin{figure}...\end{figure}\clearpage...`

Comment: ```\pagestyle{empty} \clearpage \begin{figure}[p!] ...\end{figure} \begin{figure}[p!] ...\end{figure}```